# Calling a function through UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not sure if my code is wrong, but there are no errors while compiling.

I have a refresh button where it refreshes a TableView and here's the following code:

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton:(UIButton *)sender {
UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton alloc];
[refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scanBLEDevices:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; }

- (void)scanBLEDevices:(id)sender {
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BLEService]] options:nil];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopScan:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];}
```

Is there any mistake in this code? I am unsure about this second line, whether this is allowed:

```
UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton alloc];
```

Comment: The rubber duck principle says if you can't explain what the line does then it's wrong.

Comment: where you add your refreshButton to your `UIView` hierarchy?

Comment: An action method (`IBAction`) is called by a button, and generally you create no button in it. And yes, the second contains a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "mistake" in your code, as, like you stated, it complies. The "mistake" here is more than syntax, it's context.

> If you are expecting your button to **fire** and perform your scan,
>   then you should be *calling* your method `scanBLEDevices:` inside your
>   `IBAction` method `refreshButton:`.

In your snippet, by creating a *new* `UIButton` in your refresh button method, you are merely assigning an action to a button that has not been initialized yet, *and* providing no opportunity for the button to be fired (it is created and exists *only* within this method).

Assuming you have attached your action method correctly in your storyboard, I suggest replacing your simple `IBAction` method with the following:

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self scanBLEDevices:sender];

}
```

Because your `scanBLEDevices:` method requires an `id` sender, you can pass your button along (since after all you don't use it in the BLE method anway lol).

Hopefully this should help point you in the right direction. Happy coding!

---

**NOTE:** If you are unsure about when / where `allocation` is allowed here, I suggest reading up on some common practices concerning `IBAction`s, targets, and senders when using `UIButton` elements in your code.

[UIButton - UIKit | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, real easy to understand and follow!! Works now but now I have other errors to fix.. oh well!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help!